# Google Play Developer Console - How to make app available in other countries?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-developer-api, google-play-console

We have posted one of our apps to Google Play, however, we have a user in France who wants to download our app, but it doesn't show up in Google Play, even though it shows up here in the United States.

Does anyone know how to make the app available in other countries?

Comment: The search results in Google Play are ordered by relevance, is that user searching or had the direct link? The result could be further down in the list. Has the user try to delete cache data from Google Play? Is the user device compatible? After checking this answer from chornge seems correct

Answer (score 5):

**Updated Google Play Console 2021**

```
Release / Production - Countries regions (tab) - add countries regions (footer)
```

**or**

```
Release / Testing / Open testing - Countries regions (tab) - add countries regions (footer)
```

the documentation has not changed yet, hope this helps someone searching

Answer (score 2):

#### [Filters](https://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html#other-filters)

When you upload your app to Google Play, you can select the countries in which to distribute your app under `Pricing and Distribution`. The app will then be available to users in only the countries you select.

Steps:

- Sign in to [Play Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/)
- Select your Published App
- Choose **Store Presence** dropdown on the left
- Select **Pricing and Distribution**
- Select **Manage Countries**
- Choose countries you want them to be available in.

Comment: I just checked that, and France is set to Available.  I wonder why our French customer isn't seeing it on the Play Store.

Comment: if possible, try using a VPN and setting your location to France and then checking to see if your app shows up on the play store.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Production > Countries / regions menu! (UPDATED 2023 VER.)